# Maven: Can not find the tag library descriptor

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jstl

I have this 2 errors in all my JSP

```
Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"
```

Even on my pom.xml I have this

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

and I restarted Eclipse and clean the project 100 times

Here my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```

I am using a **WebLogic Server Version: 12.1.2.0.0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have auto import? 
You should enable it or load dependencies manually:

`mvn dependency:resolve` for loading all dependencies

or `mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=groupId:artifactId:version` for loading one.

Or just try to load everything using `mvn install` (`mvn package`) - you can see difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530886/mvn-install-or-mvn-package)

Also see possible answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13285826/can-not-find-the-tag-library-descriptor-for-http-java-sun-com-jsp-jstl-core)